# Issues with binding to custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, custom-controls

I have created a custom control but have some weird issues with data binding. The control has a DependencyProperty called `Status` that requires an object of type `StatusBlockData`. If I create a `StatusBlockData` object, use it directly as DataContext for my window and bind my control with `Status={Binding .}` the binding works.

But when I create the object as property in my view `public StatusBlockData Status { get; set; }`, use the view as DataContext for the window and change the binding of my control to `Status="{Binding Status}"`, it does not work anymore.

I am majorly confused. In both cases I bind to a `StatusBlockData` object, right? Here is some code. I assume that the style for the control is not important because in the first case the binding works properly.

This is my view (the `Header` property is only for testing):

```
public ViewMainWindow()
    {
        Status = new StatusBlockData(5);
        Status.SetStatus("does not work", StatusIcon.Information);
        Header = "Binding works";
    }

    public string Header { get; set; }
    public StatusBlockData Status { get; set; }
}
```

Using the view does not work:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ViewMainWindow view = new ViewMainWindow();
    this.DataContext = view;
    view.Status.SetStatus("this is not displayed", StatusIcon.Success);
}
```

XAML looks like this (again - Header is only for testing):

```
<GrassoftUtils:StatusBlock Status="{Binding Status}" Background="Red" Width="159"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="168,101,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

But without view, it works:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    StatusBlockData Status = new StatusBlockData(5);
    this.DataContext = Status;
    Status.SetStatus("this works", StatusIcon.Information);
}
```

And the binding (and the textblock is of course empty):

```
<GrassoftUtils:StatusBlock Status="{Binding .}" Background="Red" Width="159"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="168,101,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Another weird thing I have just realized: The binding of `Status="{Binding .}"` always works, regardless of what comes behind the word `Binding`. I'd expect it to fail. Is that part of the problem?

Just to be save, this is the style for the control:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:StatusBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Controls:StatusBlock}">
                <Grid Height="24" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Visibility="{Binding Path=StatusVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
                    <Image  Height="24" Width="24" Source="{Binding StatusIcon, Converter={StaticResource StatusIconConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="28,0,0,0" Text="{Binding StatusText}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"   />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Sooner or later you *have to* start implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: I have done that throughout my project. What you see here is only for testing. That is why I have created the header property: to be sure that I don't have that problem. The `StatusBlockData` class fully implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your control exposes a dependency property of type `StatusBlockData` called `Status`? And `StatusBlockData` contains properties `StatusText` and `StatusIcon` to which you want to bind your style?

The data context for your style is not just that one custom dependency property, but the whole control. In order to reference `StatusText`, you have to reference the dependency property first. That changes the binding in your style to `Text="{Binding Status.StatusText}"`.

Comment: wow, that makes a lot of sense. Knowing that, my question sounds somewhat stupid. thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it has something to do with Template Binding.  Since, you said you had written a Custom Control.
Try this,

Eg.

```
<TextBlockText="{TemplateBinding StatusText}"/>
```

Comment: That gives an error at design time: The member "StatusText" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Comment: that was for example, can you apply TemplateBinding for Status

Comment: sry, I am not quite sure what you mean. You were talking about the style, correct?